# Add dataframes to a list with same date in r

Tags: r, list, grouping

Here is my data;

```
d1<-structure(list(`1-2006` = structure(c(1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.208, 
0.405, 0.527, 0.818, 2.2, 3, 2.2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.2, 4.6, 5.2), .Names = c("nmaxm5", 
"nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", 
"dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", 
"maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily")), `1-2007` = structure(c(0.8, 
1.4, 2, 3, 2.345, 4.085, 4.884, 4.884, 3.8, 5.2, 5.2, 5.6, 5.6, 
5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", 
"nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", 
"maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", 
"maxh18", "maxdaily")), `2-2006` = structure(c(0.8, 1, 1, 1.2, 
0.232, 0.464, 0.691, 1.32, 2.2, 3.2, 4.4, 4.2, 5.8, 5, 6.8, 7.6, 
9, 8.8), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", 
"dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", 
"maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", 
"maxdaily")), `2-2007` = structure(c(0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 0.643, 
1.218, 1.577, 3.128, 1.8, 2.4, 2.4, 3.8, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 
4), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", 
"dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", 
"maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily"
))), .Names = c("1-2006", "1-2007", "2-2006", "2-2007"))
```

I want to collect dataframes with same months (etc; january, february..) like the data below. There will be 2 dataframes under the list. Same months will be grouped under same list.

```
    out<-structure(list(january = structure(list(`1-2006` = structure(c(1.6, 
1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.208, 0.405, 0.527, 0.818, 2.2, 3, 2.2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3.2, 4.6, 5.2), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", 
"nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", 
"maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", 
"maxh18", "maxdaily")), `1-2007` = structure(c(0.8, 1.4, 2, 3, 
2.345, 4.085, 4.884, 4.884, 3.8, 5.2, 5.2, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 
5.6, 5.6, 5.6), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", 
"dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", 
"maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", 
"maxdaily"))), .Names = c("1-2006", "1-2007")), february = structure(list(
    `2-2006` = structure(c(0.8, 1, 1, 1.2, 0.232, 0.464, 0.691, 
    1.32, 2.2, 3.2, 4.4, 4.2, 5.8, 5, 6.8, 7.6, 9, 8.8), .Names = c("nmaxm5", 
    "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", 
    "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", 
    "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily")), `2-2007` = structure(c(0.4, 
    0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 0.643, 1.218, 1.577, 3.128, 1.8, 2.4, 2.4, 
    3.8, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 4), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", 
    "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", 
    "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", 
    "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily"))), .Names = c("2-2006", 
"2-2007"))), .Names = c("january", "february"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in one line:

```
out <- lapply(setNames(1:12, tolower(month.name)), function(x) d1[grepl(paste0("^", x, "-"), names(d1))])
```

Each month is then accessed as out$january, out$february, etc.

```
out$january
$`1-2006`
   nmaxm5   nmaxm10   nmaxm15   nmaxm30    dmaxm5   dmaxm10   dmaxm15   dmaxm30 maxhourly     maxh2     maxh3     maxh4     maxh5     maxh6     maxh8    maxh12    maxh18  maxdaily 
    1.600     1.600     1.600     1.600     0.208     0.405     0.527     0.818     2.200     3.000     2.200     3.000     3.000     3.000     3.000     3.200     4.600     5.200 

$`1-2007`
   nmaxm5   nmaxm10   nmaxm15   nmaxm30    dmaxm5   dmaxm10   dmaxm15   dmaxm30 maxhourly     maxh2     maxh3     maxh4     maxh5     maxh6     maxh8    maxh12    maxh18  maxdaily 
    0.800     1.400     2.000     3.000     2.345     4.085     4.884     4.884     3.800     5.200     5.200     5.600     5.600     5.600     5.600     5.600     5.600     5.600
```

Comment: Let's say I have "10-2006", this dataframe is coming after "1-2007". (Same situation for "11" and "12" months.)  Then october, november and december seem "list(0)". What should I do?

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi Ah yes, the match erred for the two-digit months. The updated code should now sort them correctly.